# Ugly fonts in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0 Windows 8.1

Tags: java, fonts, sublime-text-2, anti-aliasing, intellij-idea

I use  macType Which renders fonts beautifully elsewhere.
I tried to configure through options

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings = On
-Dswing.aatext = True
```

but nothing helped. In general InteliJ not see me `Ubuntu Bold` font, I do not know why. The sublime text 2 rendering looks much better. I'm using Windows 8.1. What to do?

I changed Parameters of `useSystemAAFontSettings` on `lcd`, but it did not help.
Although it seems to me that in Sublime Text font is like a little fuzzy, I use font Ubuntu Bold, this wine macType?

In InteliJ font seems to be fraying. In InteliJ font appears to be fraying. `Ubuntu Mono` font InteliJ does not look right, brackets [ and ] are poorly displayed.

Intelij Ubuntu Mono:

[image]

Sublime Text Ubuntu Bold:[image]

Comment: Well I guess it’s all about personal opinion. And mine is that the first example doesn’t look ugly, not even remotely. I suggest you rewrite your question to focus on the main issue: It doesn’t look like it ought to.

Comment: note that in the first example, the brackets are not displayed, whole, cut up

Comment: Daniel B what do you this about this?